# Find NumPy array rows which contain any of list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D NumPy array `a` and a list/set/1D NumPy array `b`. I would like to find those rows of `a` which contain any of `b`, i.e.,

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 3],
    [0, 1, 0]
    ])

b = np.array([1, 2])

# result: [True, False, True]
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`np.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) to find matches for any element from `b` in every element in `a`. Now, `np.in1d` would flatten arrays, so we need to reshape afterwards. Finally, since we want to find `ANY` match along each row in `a`, use `np.any` along each row. Thus, we would have an implementation like so -

```
np.in1d(a,b).reshape(a.shape).any(axis=1)
```